# Does Bootstrap having anything like the "end" class in Foundation?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying so hard to put something below a collection of items I've rendered in a Rails view.

It's an uneven number of boxes in the last row. In other words, they don't go all the way out to the right.

No matter what I do, the things I add just appear to the right of the last box. Even if I create a row. It's maddening.

Foundation has a nice `end` class that lets you start on a new line. I'm really hoping Bootstrap does as well.

Comment: I believe you can just use .pull-right

Comment: Posting your code so we can *see* what you're talking about would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing off your `.row` (i.e. `<div class="row">...</div>`) should do it, so not sure why it's not working for you - which is why it's good to include code you've done. Maybe you've overridden something with custom CSS.

That being said, a clearfix `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the last item should reset it for you, even with most custom CSS.